# Disable to Push NPM Build step results in TfsBuild to SonarQube

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sonarqube, tfsbuild

I have a UI project (HTML, CSS, Angular2.0)

I want to add this to sonarqube, we are using TFS for our build.

I have the following steps

[image]

broken down they look as follows 
**step 1**
[image]
**step 2**
[image]
**Step 3**
[image]
**Step 4**
[image]
**Step 5**
[image]
**Step 6**
[image]

the exception i get is as follows

```
 ##[error]The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (which as his name suggests only work when you have a MSBuild step). With the current tasks you can't analyze a web project like you want to do. There will be a new version of the SonarQube extension including the SonarQube Scanner for CLI that will allow to do so.

For now, the only solution, I can think of, will be for you to include the binaries of SonarQube Scanner for CLI and add a Command Line step after the npm Build one (you will need to remove the Begin Analysis and End Analysis) that will do the analysis.

More information about the Scanner for CLI [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Comment: Thanks when is the New Version of SonarQube due do you know ?

Comment: No official release date but it should come into the upcoming weeks.